# HTML/Bootstrap5 - ms-auto class does not right align items in navbar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to follow along with a video tutorial to learn bootstrap and I got stuck at the part where I'm supposed to right align items in a navbar. I checked my code against the presentors and it is identical:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg  bg-dark navbar-dark">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Frontend Bootcamp</a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">What You'll learn</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item" >
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Questions</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item" >
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Instructors</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I included ms-auto but it places everything in the ul to left align but when the presenter runs the code it is all right aligned. What could be causing this?

Comment: Your code works fine. https://prnt.sc/1swjryt. Js Fiddle LInk https://jsfiddle.net/83a6q52z/  Make sure you are loading the right version of the bootstrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example works fine see fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/mhrqopjx/2/

If you are using bootstrap 4 , just use `ml-auto` instead of `ms-auto`. this should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This was a change introduced in Bootstrap 5. Specifically, Bootstrap 5 adds the following in the `_utilities.scss` mixin:

```
.ms-auto {
  margin-left: auto !important;
}
```

The example you are looking at is using Bootstrap 5, and you are currently running Bootstrap 4. You can see this in the examples below.

**Bootstrap 4 example:**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-P5MgMn1jBN01asBgU0z60Qk4QxiXo86+wlFahKrsQf37c9cro517WzVSPPV1tDKzhku2iJ2FVgL67wG03SGnNA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg  bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Frontend Bootcamp</a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">What You'll learn</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Questions</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Instructors</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**Bootstrap 5 example:**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-6KY5s6UI5J7SVYuZB4S/CZMyPylqyyNZco376NM2Z8Sb8OxEdp02e1jkKk/wZxIEmjQ6DRCEBhni+gpr9c4tvA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg  bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Frontend Bootcamp</a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">What You'll learn</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Questions</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Instructors</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Simply update your Bootstrap to version 5 to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Update your Bootstrap version to fix the issue.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Bootstrap 5</title>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg  bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Frontend Bootcamp</a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">What You'll learn</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Questions</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Instructors</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]